# calculate difference between values in different row and different column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, plyr

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID  s1  e1  s2  e2
A   50  150 80  180
A   160 350 280 470
A   355 700 800 1150
B   100 500 150 550
B   550 1500    800 1750
```

When the ID is identical I would like to calculate the difference between values in consecutive rows but different columns (for ID A: s1 in row2 minus e1 in row1; s1 in row3 minus e1 in row2; s2 in row2 minus e2 in row1; s2 in row3 minus e2 in row2) and add these values to a new column (diff1 and diff2).

The dataframe would then look like this:

```
ID  s1  e1  s2  e2  diff1   diff2
A   50  150 80  180     
A   160 350 280 470 10  100
A   355 700 800 1150    5   330
B   100 500 150 550     
B   550 1500    800 1750    50  250
```

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance

WD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After grouping by 'ID', get the `lead` of 's1', subtract it from 'e1', and create 'diff1' as the `lag` of this output.  Similarly, the 'diff2' can be created the corresponding pairs of 's2' and 'e2' columns

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(diff1 = lag(lead(s1) - e1), diff2 = lag(lead(s2)- e2))
# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Groups: ID [2]
#   ID       s1    e1    s2    e2 diff1 diff2
#   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 A        50   150    80   180    NA    NA
#2 A       160   350   280   470    10   100
#3 A       355   700   800  1150     5   330
#4 B       100   500   150   550    NA    NA
#5 B       550  1500   800  1750    50   250
```

---

If there are multiple 's', 'e' pairs, one option with `data.table` would be to `melt` it to 'long' format and then `dcast` to 'wide' after doing the necessary calculation

```
library(data.table)
dnew <- dcast(melt(setDT(df1, keep.rownames = TRUE),
 measure = patterns("^s\\d+", "^e\\d+"), value.name = c("s", "e"))[, 
  diffs := shift(shift(s, type = "lead") - e), .(ID, variable)][],
           rn + ID ~ paste0('diff', variable), value.var = 'diffs')
df1[, names(dnew)[3:4] := dnew[, 3:4, with = FALSE]][, rn := NULL][]
#   ID  s1   e1  s2   e2 diff1 diff2
#1:  A  50  150  80  180    NA    NA
#2:  A 160  350 280  470    10   100
#3:  A 355  700 800 1150     5   330
#4:  B 100  500 150  550    NA    NA
#5:  B 550 1500 800 1750    50   250
```

Comment: I noticed that when I only have one row of ID (with one set of s1,e1,s2,e2) it does also calculate the difference with the previous row (with different ID), but I solved this by just deleting single ID rows.

Comment: @WannesDermauw  I think the `melt` requires pairwise columns.  You can either add a NA column of the corresponding 'e' column and then do the `melt`